# C# Foreach List , insert to sql database

Tags: c#, list, foreach

My bugged code for try to write full list on database mysql with INSERT.
how user correctly foreach functions?

```
NpcAI.RegisteredNpc = new CDictionnary<string, List<string>>();
NpcAI.RegisteredNpc.Add("Ballons", new List<string>()
      {
        "1", //id
        "Ballons" // name
      });

NpcAI.RegisteredNpc.Add("Ballons", new List<string>()
      {
        "2", //id
        "lons" // name
      });



foreach(npc in NpcAI.RegisteredNpc)
{
     using (SqlDatabaseClient client = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
     {
         client.ClearParameters(); 
         client.SetParameter("id", (object) npc[id]);
         client.SetParameter("name", (object) npc[name]; 
         client.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO `npc`(`id`, `name`) VALUES (@id, @name)");
     }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: error in "  foreach(npc in NpcAI.RegisteredNpc)  "  Gravità Codice Descrizione Progetto File Riga Stato eliminazione
Errore CS0030 Non è possibile convertire il tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' in 'string'. Androm C:\Users\Stefano\Desktop\Andrest\Game\Npcs\NpcAI.cs 44 Attivo

Comment: What error? Did try to debug the code to figure out what's wrong with it ?

Comment: What IDE are you using ? Your code editor should tell you that there is an error. Also, what are you trying to achieve. Your code doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. Can you describe what you want to do ?

Comment: note: as mentioned by an other [steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve), why do you add two elements with the same key "Ballons" in the dictionary ?  What is this `CDictionnary` implementation ? Once again, what is the purpose of this code ? What do you mean to do with it ?

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) Please don't comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` should be declared like so:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> npc in NpcAI.RegisteredNpc)
{
    // code
}
```

Here is your full editer and working code, as long as there is no SQL error.

```
NpcAI.RegisteredNpc = new CDictionnary<string, List<string>>();

NpcAI.RegisteredNpc.Add("Ballons", new List<string>()
{
    "1", //id    
    "Ballons" // name
});

NpcAI.RegisteredNpc.Add("Ballons", new List<string>()
{
    "2", //id
        "lons" // name    
});


foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> npc in NpcAI.RegisteredNpc)
{

    using(SqlDatabaseClient client = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
    {
        client.ClearParameters(); 
        client.SetParameter("id", npc.Value[0]); // will get the first value so it'll be 1 or 2
        client.SetParameter("name", npc.Value[1]); // will get the second value, so it'll be either "Ballons" or "lons"     
        client.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO `npc`(`id`, `name`) VALUES (@id, @name)");
    }
}
```

Comment: note: edited again, my code had syntax errors. It should work now, as long as your `SqlDatabaseClient` works

Comment: if CDictionnary is really a Dictionary I fail to see how you can add two elements with the same key "Ballons"

Comment: You won't. You'll add one with the name "Ballons" and the other with the name "lons". That what youre code atempted to do. 

What you do you want in the database in the end ? What do you want the DB to look like after the insert ?

Comment: If, instead, CDictionnary contains some logic to _merge_ the lists with the same key then we have a problem in the logic that saves the list data

Comment: @Wndrr the key is in the Add line not on the list values. I suppose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156150/discussion-between-wndrr-and-steve).